# jquery opacity transition for image

Tags: jquery

Hello I am attempting to add a transition to the `jquery` code that makes it so that when the image (`foreground-image`) is hovered over, it is delayed for `.25seconds` with a fade in and the same for fade out

````
```function checkPosition() {
    $('.foreground-image').css('opacity', '0.0');

    // Desktop Only
     if (window.innerWidth > 991) {
      $('.collection-item-5.brand-collections').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.foreground-image').css('opacity', '1.0');
        var mySrc = $(this).find('.image-131').attr('src');
        $('.foreground-image').attr('src', mySrc);
    });

    $('.collection-item-5.brand-collections').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.foreground-image').css('opacity', '0.0');
    });

     }```
````

Answer (score 0):

CSS transitions allow you to change property values smoothly (from one value to another), over a given duration.
Check following example:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_buttons_fade1

Comment: Links die over time.  Please include all the relevant information in the answer (even if it's just copying from your link into a snippet).  Ideally tailored to the question (eg with an image instead of btn).   For more info, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259